# ActiveSupport::JSON decode hash losing symbols

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to serialize and deserialize a hash. When the hash is deserailized, the keys are de-symbolized; e.g. not more :one, rather "one".

From rails console:

```
>>h = { :one =>1, :two => "two"}
{:one=>1, :two=>"two"}
>>j = ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(h)
"{\"one\":1,\"two\":\"two\"}"
>>h2 = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(j)
{"one"=>1, "two"=>"two"}
>>h2[:one]
nil
>>h[:one]
1
```

I've switched to using Marshal.dump/load for now. However, I wanted to throw this out there to see if there was a way to keep this in JSON (just for readability).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
h2 = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(j).symbolize_keys
```

Comment: Note: this does not symbolize the keys recursively.

Comment: Nor works for an array containing JSONs objects i.e. `[{'id':1}, {'id': '2'}, ...]`. Tim Cull solution works tho.

Answer (score 19):

`JSON.parse(j, {:symbolize_names => true})` should be slightly better because it (I assume) never creates string keys in the first place and hence conserves memory for large hashes with the same keys repeated often

Comment: I guess what people really want is a https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess so it works like Rails does it by default, i.e.: allow both `h['one']` and `h[:one]`

Comment: So: `JSON.parse(j, {:symbolize_names => true}).with_indifferent_access`. Note that this only works in Rails, so for example plain old Ruby classes executed by background processes might not have access to the Hash method `.with_indifferent_access` which ActiveSupport defines.

Comment: PS: it also symbolize keys recursively.